# Version number in npm package and module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am authoring an npm package that has a module and command-line executable. The npm package [has a version](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#requirements).

I would like my module to know about this version, so that I can report it from `my_executable -v` and otherwise use it in the output (e.g. "Generated by MyPackage v1.3.2"). However, I don't want to type the same version number in two places (in my module and my `package.json`) because at some point I'm guaranteed to mess up and forget to update one or the other. How can I either…

- …export the version from my module, and have the `package.json` read the version from my module?

  - *With a Ruby gem I can do this, because a `gemspec` file is pure Ruby code that can load the module and populate the parameters from derived code. I assume that's not possible with npm/package.json?*
- …or, read the version specified in `package.json` from my module?

  - *Is the `package.json` guaranteed to be installed along with my module, in a known location? How would I pull it in? Manually reading the JSON and parsing it?*

---

**Edit**: a simple `let pkg = require('./package.json')` does not work in my case, because of my project file structure:

```
mypackage/
  bin/myexecutable    # uses require('../lib/mymodule.js')
  lib/mymodule.js     # needs to load package.json
  package.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the version of your package from `package.json` as follows:

```
let pkg = require('./package.json');
```

Access `pkg.version` to get the version e.g.:

```
console.log(pkg.version);
```

If `package.json` is not in the same directory as the file you are executing:

```
let pkg = require(__dirname + '/path/to/package.json')
```

Comment: That looks nice and terse! What is `./` in this case? The directory for the module? The directory for my `module.js` file? Or the CWD of the command? Basically: do I need to use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) against `__dirname` to be safe?

Comment: Root directory of module - which will be where the `package.json` is

Comment: Actually, I believe it is relative to the file you are executing. So whatever the binary file you are executing relative path to that.

Comment: That appears to do it. In my specific case—where the path from both executable and module to the package is `../package.json`—I can use `require('../package.json')` in my module and it works, without needing to resort to `path.resolve()` or `__dirname`. Thanks for your help. I'll leave this question open a little longer in case alternative suggestions come along, but otherwise this seems like an acceptable anser.

Comment: Any alternatives I am aware of use `fs.readFile` followed by `JSON.parse`. Nothing as simple as this, but feel free to keep it open to see if anyone returns anything better

Answer (score 1):

1) The universal solution is:

```
const path = require('path');
// will be used to check file existence
const {accessSync} = require("fs");

function getMainPackage() {
  let mainModuleName, pathToPackage;

  const mainModuleNameOnError = {
    name: "unknown",
    version: "unknown",
  };

  try {
    mainModuleName = require.main.paths.find((modulesPath) => {
      pathToPackage = path.resolve(modulesPath, "..", "package.json");
      try {
        accessSync(pathToPackage);
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return mainModuleNameOnError;
  }

  return (mainModuleName)
    ? require(pathToPackage);
    : mainModuleNameOnError;
}

//example
const pkg = getMainPackage();
console.log(pkg.version);
```

2) If you know where is your package.json placed:

```
let pkg = require(<the_packagejson_folder> + './package.json');
console.log(pkg.version);
```

3) If your application is launched with 'npm start', you can simply use:

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

See [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) for more details.

Comment: As the author of the package and software, don't I always know where the `package.json` is? Under what circumstances is your #1 required?

Comment: When you can't use more simple solution from #2 or #3. Time to time you can find the package.json, so you will get mainModuleNameOnError object

Comment: Under what circumstances does "time to time" occur? (And I think you meant "…you **can't** find…".)

Comment: The circumstances is you don't require any file from `node_modules` folder.